# Can't play video from instagram API response

Tags: php, instagram-api

I get this response from the PHP code using the API: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/user_defined_tag_name.

Now, I am trying to play the video in browser by using the URL from   "display_src". However, i was not able to play it.

Any help will be appreciated!!

```
"thumbnail_src": "https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/t51.2885-15\/e15\/c157.0.406.406\/15035073_1165170080216101_8101167348074938368_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTM4OTY2NjA5Mjc3OTU2NjMxNg%3D%3D.2.c",
                    "is_video": true,
                    "id": "1389666092779566316",
                    "display_src": "https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/t51.2885-15\/s640x640\/e15\/15035073_1165170080216101_8101167348074938368_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTM4OTY2NjA5Mjc3OTU2NjMxNg%3D%3D.2",
                    "video_views": 6
```

Comment: how can you play the video from `display_src`, check the extension it is jpg

Comment: So what's way out. I want to extract the video and images to be extracted from instagram based on specific hashtag.

Comment: I though it's video because in `is_video` key it says true. so it belied me.

Comment: share the complete response or you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634194/instagram-api-retrieve-only-videos

Comment: @HappyCoding, you can check full JSON at [link](http://85.17.76.181/~reiselivsmessen/public/instagram) and format is using [link](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

Comment: @HappyCoding, Are you there? I need help, could you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#) doc, response will be like something below:

```
 "type": "video",
    "videos": {
                "low_resolution": {
                    "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_102.mp4",
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 480
                },
                "standard_resolution": {
                    "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_101.mp4",
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 640
                }
```

Now if you save the response in `$result`

```
<?php foreach ($result as $post) {
    if ($post->type == "image") { ?>
        <!-- Go for your image option -->
    <?php } 

    else { ?>
       <!-- video will be in $post->videos->standard_resolution->url key -->
    <?}
} ?>
```

Comment: Lately, i am in sandbox mode. when i use the API [link](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) with the access token provided by [link](https://elfsight.com/service/generate-instagram-access-token/) using postman. Then, it shows empty data array response.

Comment: Is this due to sandbox mode?

Comment: result will be same in both the mode live or sandbox

Comment: {
  "pagination": {
    "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"
  },
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  },
  "data": []
}

Comment: data always remains empty despite changing the hashtag.  I have used the API of the instagram that is: https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/love/media/recent?access_token=2168131058.130c568.32a8064cede74168b68f13dbec8e1a42

Comment: how you are getting the data previously?